# How to create a table which has large amount of text with centralized text

Tags: tables

[image]Sample image

What all should I do to create a table as shown in the figure

Using something like `\multirow` makes it very difficult for manually splitting the line

Using `p{some cm}` in table leaves other columns with single entries unformatted, licking the top rule of the cell..

How can these entries be centered in the cells

Tried something like

```
\begin{table}[!h]

\begin{center}

\caption{Summary .....}

\begin{tabularx}{0.30\textwidth}{|c|X|X|X|}

\hlne

\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Lot size} & \textwidth{Inventory Cost Item} & \textwidth{Carbon Emission \& Enviornmentall Cost} \\
\hline

some text   & some text & Order cost inventory holding cost & Carbon emission form logistic and wearhouse in linear in the order quantity \\ \hline

\end{table}

\end{center}

\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have attempted anything to create this table yourself - we normally don't encourage please-do-it-for-me questions? It would be very nice if you could provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far.

Comment: @Raptor What do you mean by centred entries? There is nothing centred in the image you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided wasn't close to compilable: you had environments closing out of order, typos in commands, among other things.

Your question isn't totally clear, but I believe you're looking to vertically center the content of each row instead of having everything start at the top of the cell. You can achieve this with

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}
```

which sets the `tabularx` `X` column to use the `m` column type (vertically centered) instead of the default `p` column type (top aligned).

Other notes: don't use the `center` environment inside the `table` environment: this will add extra vertical spacing. Just putting `\centering` inside the `table` environment is sufficient. But that's not necessary in my example below, since the table spans the full `\textwidth` anyway.

I also added `booktabs` commands to the example below for better spacing and appearance of the table, and set the `X` columns `\raggedright` since it's hard to do full justification well in this narrow a column width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Summary\dots}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Authors & Lot Size Model & Inventory Cost Terms 
  & Carbon Emission and Environmental Cost Terms \\
\midrule
some text & some text & Order cost inventory holding cost 
  & Carbon emission form logistic and warehouse is linear in the order quantity \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]